# Is it possible to link all contents of a media folder on a page?

Tags: media-library, templates

New to working with sitecore, and not really sure if what I'm looking into trying to do is even possible. I certainly can't figure it out myself.

In short, I want a page which will list all the contents of a chosen `media library` folder; ideally giving a preview image, the file name as a link, some other details as text, in the order they appear in the folder.

`Layout/styling` isn't important so long as that can be manipulated.

Is this a thing that's possible, or am I barking up the wrong tree? (and if it is possible, tips would be appreciated!)

Working in Sitecore 8 if relevant, and probably need the idiot's guide if there is such a thing.

(and new here, so apologies if anything about the question is improper, will amend as required).

Comment: Any chance using SXA? This would be a trivial task using Page List or Navigation with Rendering Variants.

Comment: @MichaelWest Pretty sure not, no.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which part of this task you're having a problem with, or how much of it you're expecting to find in a ready-to-use widget. There are Sitecore APIs to get your chosen media library folder as an Item object, and then to get the children of that Item object. Using these APIs, you can generate HTML in a Razor or ASPX page, like you do when designing the HTML for any page in Sitecore.